# When using JavaScript to dynamically update content,the Django message doesnt show up

Tags: javascript, python, django

When I write a template about registration,I need a JavaScript code to dynamically change the info to show.However,doing this causes the reminding info disappear.How can I solve it?

Here are the template Code and the view

```
{% if messages %}
      {% for message in messages %}
        <div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }}">{{ message }}</div>
      {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="id_role">Select role:</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="id_role" name="role">
        <option value="teacher">Teacher</option>
        <option value="student" selected>Student</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  <div class="form-group" id="teacher-fields"  style="display: {% if form.role.value != 'student' %}block{% else %}none{% endif %}">
      ...</div>
    <div class="form-group" id="student-fields" style="display: {% if form.role.value == 'student' %}block{% else %}none{% endif %}">
     ...</div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
  </form>
<script>
    // Listen for changes to role selection and update form fields
    const roleSelect = document.getElementById('id_role');
    const teacherFields = document.getElementById('teacher-fields');
    const studentFields = document.getElementById('student-fields');
    roleSelect.addEventListener('change', () => {
      if (roleSelect.value === 'teacher') {
        teacherFields.style.display = 'block';
        studentFields.style.display = 'none';
      } else {
        studentFields.style.display = 'block';
        teacherFields.style.display = 'none';
      }
    });
  </script>
```

---

```
def register(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    if request.POST.get('role') == 'teacher':
        form = TeacherRegistrationForm(request.POST)
    else:
        form = StudentRegistrationForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()

        messages.success(request, 'Your account has been created! You are now able to log in')
        return redirect('account/login')
    else:
        for field, errors in form.errors.items():
            for error in errors:
                messages.error(request, f"{field}: {error}")
else:
    if request.GET.get('role') == 'teacher':
        form = TeacherRegistrationForm()
    else:
        form = StudentRegistrationForm()
return render(request, 'accounts/register.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Did you check if your divs with id `teacher-fields` and `student-fields` are not nested each other, they should be separate, else the class added on teacher-fields will be applied to the inner.

Comment: they are separate.I omit the </div> accidentally.@ThomasJohn